# Entity Framework - Log the SQL Query that caused SaveChanges to throw Exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, exception

I am using **Entity Framework 6 in a MVC web application** and I am currently wrapping all calls to `SaveChanges` method in a `try..catch` block. **Whenever an exception is caught, the exception details are being logged to a file and are also being emailed to a specific email address.**

Now, **I also want the log entry and the email to include the actual SQL Query** that caused `SaveChanges` to throw the exception. I understand that the exception can sometimes also be thrown even before a SQL Query is generated and executed, I just need the SQL in cases where the exception is caused because of an error occurring while execution of Query by SQL Server.

I know of a few ways to log the SQL Queries being executed.

[**DbContext.Database.Log Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#Log)

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 
}
```

**[Registering interceptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj556606.aspx#Interceptors)** and **[ObjectQuery.ToTraceString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring(v=vs.110).aspx)**

I can log all SQL Queries using any of the above mentioned methods but I am not sure **How to identify the SQL that caused the error?**
I was thinking of using `Database.Log` method to **keep track of the latest executed query for each Request using some session variable**(My DbContext instance is Per Request Scoped) and just assume the latest executed Query in Session variable to be the culprit in case an exception occurs. This won't work in all cases as it might not always be the latest executed Query that causes the exception, the exception could have been thrown by EF due to some failed validation or something else(in which case I won't need to have any SQL logged).

**Is there any way I could pin-point the Query that causes the exception on SaveChanges?** Either using any of the mentioned logging methods in combination with some other property or may be a different approach altogether?

Comment: You want to get validation errors, right?

Comment: Register custom [`DbCommandInterceptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.dbcommandinterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx), override `*Executed` methods and examine `command` and `exceptionContext.Exception`

Comment: @AdilMammadov No, I need the SQL that was executed in case exception is thrown by SaveChanges.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the idea, I'll look into that.